Differences when using regular normal approximation vs sampling proportion of binomial distribution
When learning about sampling proportions of the normal distribution, I was told that you can use either method and get the same answer. However, upon completing some calculations to test this I got largely different results.
The question was:

A test is composed of 20 multiple choice questions, each with 4 answers, only one of which is correct. What is the probability of getting a score of at least 2 correct when randomly guessing every question. You may use normal approximation.

So I tried this out with both regular and sampling proportions.
Regular Normal Distribution

$n=20$,
$p=\frac{1}{4}$

Therefore we can obtain:

$\mu=5$ and $\sigma=\frac{\sqrt{15}}{2}$

Now solving for $P(X>1)$:

$P(X>1)\approx P\left(z>\frac{-8}{\sqrt{15}}\right)$

And using a table of z-scores, this is approximately 0.9808
Sampling Proportion Of Normal Distribution

$n=20$,
$p=\frac{1}{4}$

Therefore we can obtain:

$\mu=\frac{1}{4}$ and $\sigma=\frac{\sqrt{15}}{40}$

Now solving for $P(\hat{p}>0.1)$:

$P(\hat{p}>0.1)\approx P\left(z>\frac{-2\sqrt{15}}{15}\right)$

And using a table of z-scores, this is approximately 0.9394
Why is the answer not the same, and does it have something to do with the greater than and greater than or equal to being basically equivalent in sampling proportions.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Second part is not correct.$p_n'$ is a normal random variable with $ \mu=p $ and $ \sigma= \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}} $ check.It is advisable to do the continuity correction inform yourself.
In part one, you consider x=1 then in part two, you have to consider $ \frac {1}{20} \neq 0.1$ with $ \frac {1}{20}\rightarrow z=\frac{-8}{\sqrt{15}} $ same as part one

Those are the values of μ and σ I use. What is continuity correction?
